# RDS read-only replicas of different size than master

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I have two m1.large RDS instances, a master and a read-replica.

The master is able to keep up with the write load just fine, but occasionally read load on the replica comes to a point where the latency is a little too close for comfort.

Is it possible to have a replica that is larger than the master instance? I haven't see any confirmation if this is possible or if there are any gotchas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it is possible with many ways:

### Via management console

1. In RDS instance details, push "Instance action" button and select Create read replica
2. First field is EC2 type used for this read replica, just choose whatever you want

### Via CloudFormation template

Just create new item of type `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` and set parameter `SourceDBInstanceIdentifier` to master DBInstance. You can set parameters as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this shouldn't be a problem.